# Laravel load more not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to do load more using jquery

```
  $response=Event::where(function ($query){
            $query->whereDate('event_start_date','>=',Carbon::now());
            $query->orWhereDate('event_end_date','>=',Carbon::now());

        })->orderBy('event_start_date', 'ASC')
            ->limit(12)->get() ;
```

I have 10 posts where id=4 ,5,6 post event will come end because of event_start_date is 30th jan

every time when i click load more i was sending last event id so post 4,5,6 is not appearing because i have condition `$query->where('id','>',$request->id);`

Sample db data

```
id |event_start_date | event_end_date
1 |2019-01-15 20:00:00|2019-01-15 20:00:00
2 |2019-01-15 20:00:00|2019-01-15 20:00:00
3 |2019-01-15 20:00:00|2019-01-15 20:00:00
4 |2019-01-27 20:00:00|2019-01-30 20:00:00
5 |2019-01-28 20:00:00|2019-01-31 20:00:00
6 |2019-01-29 20:00:00|2019-01-31 20:00:00
7 |2019-01-15 20:00:00|2019-01-15 20:00:00
8 |2019-01-15 20:00:00|2019-01-15 20:00:00
9 |2019-01-15 20:00:00|2019-01-15 20:00:00
10 |2019-01-15 20:00:00|2019-01-15 20:00:00
```

can any one help me how i can fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not send page get attribute and use as your `$query->where('id','>',$request->id)` then use below query

```
$response=Event::when(isset($request->id),function ($query)use ($request){
        $query->where('id','>',$request->id);
    })->where(function ($query){
        $query->whereDate('event_start_date','>=',Carbon::now());
        $query->orWhereDate('event_end_date','>=',Carbon::now());

    })->orderBy('event_start_date', 'ASC')
      ->take(12)->get() ;
```

if you send page get attribute like `xyz.com?page=1`

```
$response=Event::whereDate('event_start_date','>=',Carbon::now())
                 ->orWhereDate('event_end_date','>=',Carbon::now())
                 ->orderBy('event_start_date', 'ASC')->paginate(12);
```

Comment: then you send offset means total load pages count and this count multiply  by pagination limit and use this query `$query->skip($count*12);` instead `$query->where('id','>',$request->id);`